# JUnit test with parametrized method

Tags: java, junit

Here is a unit test class :

```
MyUnitTestSetup myUnitTestSetup ;

public void setUp(String myParam){
  myUnitTestSetup = new MyUnitTestSetup(myParam);
}

@Test
public void test1(){
  setUp("value1");
  //do some stuff with myParam = "value1";
}

@Test
public void test2(){
  setUp("value2");
  //do some stuff with myParam = "value2";
}
```

I want to execute test1 with "value1" and test2 with "value2". Parameterized Unit test are not convenient because they would execute test1 for "value1" and "value2" and test2 for "value1" and "value2 which is not what I want.

I though about :

- calling the setup method each time I do a test.
- using @Rule annotation :

  ```
  static String myParam;
  MyUnitTestSetup myUnitTestSetup ;

  @Before
  public void setUp(){
    myUnitTestSetup = new MyUnitTestSetup(myParam);
  }

  @Rule
  public TestRule rule = new TestRule() {     
      @Override
      public Statement apply(final Statement base, final Description desc) {
          return new Statement() {
              @Override
              public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                  if(desc.getMethodName().equals("test1"))
                      myParam = "value1";
                  ...
              }
          };
      }
  }

  @Test
  public void test1(){
    //do some stuff with myParam = "value1";
  }

  @Test
  public void test2(){
    //do some stuff with myParam = "value2";
  }
  ```

But I am wondering if there is a cleaner & smarter way of doing this. I would have thought of something like :

```
MyUnitTestSetup myUnitTestSetup ;

@Before
public void setUp(String myParam){
  myUnitTestSetup = new MyUnitTestSetup(myParam);
}

@Test(myParam="value1")
public void test1(){
  //do some stuff with myParam = "value1";
}

@Test(myParam="value2")
public void test2(){
  //do some stuff with myParam = "value2";
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: I wrote up a library with named parameterizations which, among other things, let you do this by annotating tests with `@OnlyIf` or `@OnlyIfNot`. Unfortunately, I never got around to documenting the thing... but feel free to take a look: https://code.launchpad.net/namedparameterizedrunner

Comment: May be this will help you http://netbeans.dzone.com/articles/junit-little-beyond-test-after?page=0,1

Answer (score 3):

Am I missing something here? Why not just set it as the first thing in the test call or call the method that sets things up.

```
@Test
public void test1(){
  myParam = "value1"; //set the value?
  ...
}

@Test
public void test2(){
  setupMyParam("value2"); // or this?
  ...
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I do in my first example. But I was wondering if something cleaner exists. For example, if you need to setup your test without any parameter, you will do it in an outside method annotated with @Before. You don't call it on the first line of each test method ...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if using [TestNG](http://testng.org) is an option for you, but if you can, TestNG lets you 1) pass parameters directly to test methods and 2) define as many data providers as you want per class. For example:

```
@DataProvider
public Object[][] dp1() {
    return new Object[][] {
        new Object[] { "value1"};
    }
}

@Test(dataProvider = "dp1")
public void test1(String value) {
    // will receive "value1"
}

@DataProvider
public Object[][] dp2() {
    return new Object[][] {
        new Object[] { "value2"};
    }
}

@Test(dataProvider = "dp2")
public void test2(String value) {
    // will receive "value2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [JUnitParams](https://code.google.com/p/junitparams/) library. With it you could do:

```
@Test
@Parameters({ new MyUnitTestSetup("value1") })
public void test1(MyUnitTestSetup myUnitTestSetup1) {
  // do some stuff with myUnitTestSetup1
}

@Test
@Parameters({ new MyUnitTestSetup("value2") })
public void test2(MyUnitTestSetup myUnitTestSetup2) {
  // do some stuff with myUnitTestSetup2
}
```